# copy a list of files from gcs to local

Tags: copy, wildcard, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

I have a gcs bucket with many files

```
gs://bucket/file_0001.txt
gs://bucket/file_0002.txt
...
gs://bucket/file_1000.txt
```

In a juputer notebook, I can copy everything to local with something like

```
subprocess.run(f"gsutil -m cp {gcs_path}/*.txt {local_path}/".strip().split())
```

Now suppose I am given a list of file names

```
f = ['file_0123', 'file_0456', 'file_0789']
```

My question is, how can I copy the files in this list, without a for loop?

EDIT: In a simpler setup, I just want to copy all the files within a numeric range, e.g., file_0010, file_0011, ..., file_0100. How can I do that? I found using regex to be very messy..

Comment: Have you tried applying [wildcard patterns](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) `gsutil cp gs://bucket/file_*.txt`?

Comment: @CatherineO I only want to copy a subset of the files, given by a python list